# "The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing database." - No matter what - even with replace?

Tags: restore, ssms, replace

I have a strange problem. I have been able to restore + overwrite databases for years on our SQL Server yet suddenly I seem to be unable to overwrite any databases.

I should be system admin, there is nobody else who can change settings.

I can restore a database back over itself without any trouble.
Overwriting to another database causes me the below error:

> *Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 2
>   The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing database.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.*

For example, I can create 2 brand new databases, try to restore one to the other, or save to file then restore, and I get the above error message.

It's like the replace function is having no effect.

This happens on SQL Server 2008 R2.
I have this problem both on the server itself on SQL Management Studio 10.50.6560.0.
And on my local PC on SQL Management Studio (v17.9.1) 14.0.17289.0.

I've tried this in both the GUI and using SQL script:

```
*RESTORE DATABASE [Database2] FILE = 'Database1' FROM DISK = 'G:\MSSQL\TempBackups\database1.bak' WITH NORECOVERY, 
MOVE 'Database1' TO 'd:\MSSQL\DATA\Database2.mdf',
MOVE 'Database1_log' TO 'm:\MSSQL\LOGS\Database2_log.ldf',
STATS = 5,
REPLACE*
```

Any ideas on what this could be or things to try? I feel like I've trawled the Internet for any script references I can try and nothing is working.

Comment: Did you try using different filename instead of Database2.mdf and Database2_log.ldf?

Comment: Yes - same result.

Comment: And you are using WITH REPLACE while using the RESTORE command (if using the GUI, it is found under Options -> Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE) if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I've tried that both in the GUI and via script.

Comment: Can you run the following to confirm what's in the backup covers everything your script is expecting. RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'G:\MSSQL\TempBackups\database1.bak'

Comment: How did you take the backups ? Make sure you use `INIT` so the backups are not appended into a single file !